# Regex for string that has 5 numbers or IND/5numbers

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to build a regex to match 5 digit numbers or those 5 digit numbers preceded by IND/

`10223` match to return 10223
`IND/10110` match to return 10110
`ID is 11233` match to return 11233
`Ref is:10223` match to return 10223
`Ref is: th10223` not match

`SBI12234` not match
`MRF/10234` not match
`RBI/10229` not match

I have used the foll. Regex which selects the 5 digit correctly using word boundary concept. But not sure how to allow IND and not allow anything else like MRF, etc:
/b/d{5}/b

If I put (IND)? At beginning of regex then it won't help. Any hints?

Comment: And what should be the return for `123456789`? or `12345/12345`

Comment: Nothing As it is not 5 digit

Comment: What language is this regex being implemented in? You haven't tagged one.

Comment: But why `IND/1011` return `10110` and `12345/12345` returns nothing?

Comment: How about: `IND/(\d{5})\b` ? The number you want is in group 1.

Comment: But IND is optional so does that work

Comment: If "only IND/12345 should match", why does "ID is 12345" also match?

Comment: @dvo what is meaning of ?:

Comment: @variable see my answer below. `(?: <pattern>)` is a non-capture group so you can wrap things in a group without actually capturing it for use in your code. Keeps things cleaner after a match. Remove the `?:` and leave parenthesis if you care about what text came before your match (numbers).

Answer (score 3):

Use a [*look behind*](https://regular-expressions.com/lookaround.html):

```
(?<=^IND\/|^ID is |^)\d{5}\b
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/bE5erNRihcquDx).

Because the look behind doesn’t consume any input, the entire match is your target number (ie there’s no need to use a group).

Comment: What does ?<= mean

Comment: `(<=...)` is a “look behind”, which asserts (without consuming) that the preceding characters match `...`. For a detailed explanation, see https://regular-expressions.com/lookaround.html

Comment: `Ref is:10223` match to return 10223 this does not match

Comment: Your original question specified only `"ID is nnnnn"` and `"IND/nnnnn"`; nothing about `"Ref is:nnnnn"`. Please don’t edit the question like that. Ask a new question if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Variable length lookbehind is not supported by python, use alternation instead:

```
(?:(?<=IND/| is[: ])\d{5}|^\d{5})(?!\d)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NL4S1I/1)

Answer (score 1):

This should work: `(?<=IND/|\s|^)(\d{5})(?=\s|$)` .

Comment: \b will match in between `B12345`, which you want to exclude. It's obvious that the criteria is not word boundary but which character(s) preceed. `\s` does that, it matches space or space-like utf-8 characters or a newline in a flattened multiline match (switch `/s`).

Comment: @Dinu `\b` will *not* match in between `B12455`; in regex land, numbers are “word characters”.

Comment: How about using ?: instead if ?<= as I only need to 5 digit number as output

Comment: @Bohemian Ah, you're right... @variable I don't know, use `\b` if you like, I would not use "word boundary" for a search that has none to do with words or boundaries between them :) I would use character classes adapted to your actual input samples.

Comment: @variable - that will capture into `$0` that you seem to use. This is turning into a regexp tutorial which stackoverflow obviously isn't. Just use it and see if it works. If it doesn't, get back here :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `(?:IND\/|ID is |^)\b(\d{5})\b`

Explanation:

`(?: ALLOWED TEXT)`: A non-capture group with all allowed segments inside. In your example, `IND\/` for `"IND/"`, `ID is` for `"ID is ..."`, and `^` for the beginning of the string (in case of only the number / no text at start: `12345`).

`\b(\d{5})\b`: Your existing pattern w/ capture group for 5-digit number

Comment: Yes, but it still captures in `$0` which he is using as a result :) he is not using capturing `(\d{5})` in his sample regexp either. So he's using the full match to continue.

Comment: @Dinu Good point. Just the way his question is worded where he has an example string but says "should return" only the numbers, I figure capturing the 5-digit number is his end goal. Not 100% sure about python, but usually the match will have the full matched string along with the capture groups so he could still access both.

Comment: Thanks what if the 'id is...' part is really any random string?

Comment: Well, if you just change `(?:` to either `(?=` (right) or `(?<=` (left) he's safe.

Comment: @variable See my answer below. Just use `\s` to match a space it will match any number preceded by a space or `IND/`

Comment: `Ref is:10223` match to return 10223 does not match

Comment: @variable you need to edit this regex to allow all your allowed patterns. Ex: to allow "Ref is:#####", add `|Ref is:` to the beginning part of the regex where I wrote "ALLOWED TEXT"

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this will need some logic to it. The regex can find the 5 digits, but maybe a second regex pattern to find IND, then join them together if need be.  Not sure if you are using Python, .Net, or Java, but should be doable

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: I tried to comment.  I don't have 50 or more reputation points so I can only comment on my own posts until then.